# fbprophet returns Memory Error during prediction on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, out-of-memory, facebook-prophet

I was testing some simple predictions with fbProphet on Python 3.8 when I got a memory error. The code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt

Z = np.random.normal(0,1,10000) 

Z1 = np.random.normal(0,1,10000)
Z2 = np.random.normal(0,1,10000)

p = 0.7

X = Z1

Y = p*X+sqrt(1-p**2)*Z


from fbprophet import Prophet

ds = np.linspace(0,8999,9000)
y = Y[:9000]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ds,Y)),columns = ['ds','y'])

m = Prophet()
m.fit(df)
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=1000)
forecast = m.predict(future)
fig1 = m.plot(forecast)
```

The error it returned was

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.71 PiB for an array with shape (240026674167316,) and data type float64
```

What is generating this error? (I am using Ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and I was mislabeling my "ds" and "y" columns.  Make sure the "ds" labeled column is a datestamp/datetime and the "y" column is the value.